I'm getting empty response in AWS Transcribe Streaming
I'm trying to build realtime speach to text transcription in node.js using AWS transcribe. I'm sure that the audio is transferred from react to node.js through socket.io and I have cross verified by creating writeStream and appending the audio chunks and the audio is playing from that file. But the AWS transcribe service results empty response.
Tech stack:

React.js
Node.js
Socket.io
@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming

Code:
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const {
  TranscribeStreamingClient,
  StartStreamTranscriptionCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS for all origins

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*", // Allow all origins (or specify your frontend's URL)
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

const transcribeClient = new TranscribeStreamingClient({
  region: "us-west-2",
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected");

  let audioQueue = [];

  socket.on("audio", (chunk) => {
    audioQueue.push(new Uint8Array(chunk));
  });

  const audioStream = async function* () {
    while (true) {
      if (audioQueue.length > 0) {
        yield { AudioEvent: { AudioChunk: audioQueue.shift() } };
      } else {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // Wait for more data
      }
    }
  };

  const command = new StartStreamTranscriptionCommand({
    LanguageCode: "en-US",
    MediaSampleRateHertz: 16000,
    MediaEncoding: "pcm",
    AudioStream: audioStream(),
  });

  const startTranscription = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await transcribeClient.send(command);
      console.log(response.$metadata)
      for await (const event of response.TranscriptResultStream) {
        console.log(event)
        if (event.TranscriptEvent) {
          const transcriptResults = event.TranscriptEvent.Transcript.Results;
          transcriptResults.forEach((result) => {
            if (result.Alternatives.length > 0) {
              const transcriptText = result.Alternatives[0].Transcript;
              socket.emit("transcript", transcriptText);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error streaming transcription:", error);
      socket.emit("error", error.message);
    }
  };

  startTranscription();

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
});

server.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 4000");
});



Output:
Server is running on port 4000
Client connected
{
  httpStatusCode: 200,
  requestId: 'dfbe7ba4-2340-48bf-8d68-d220cd13be2d',
  extendedRequestId: undefined,
  cfId: undefined,
  attempts: 1,
  totalRetryDelay: 0
}
{ TranscriptEvent: { Transcript: { Results: [] } } }

Can you help me to solve this issue.
Is there any different approach to achieve my goal.

My brother in code, I had the same issues but managed to fix it by converting the Float32Array audio stream output to PCM in a Uint8Array as opposed to a Int16Array which is what I had originally. Weirdly enough I had transcriptions working when sending the same data in a Uint8Array to a Python WebSocket server first and then to AWS via the Python SDK. Anyway, here is the conversion code:
function convertFloat32ToPCM16(input: Float32Array): Uint8Array {
  const output = new Uint8Array(input.length * 2); // Each PCM16 value will be split into two Uint8 values
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
    const int16 = s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7fff;
    output[i * 2] = int16 & 0xff; // Lower 8 bits
    output[i * 2 + 1] = (int16 >> 8) & 0xff; // Upper 8 bits
  }
  return output;
}

